# How is the currentScope property of the $stateChangeStart event object arrived upon?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to understand a strange error I'm getting when using ui-router's `$state.transitionTo` function, and I think knowing more about the `$stateChangeStart` event, accessible in the event handler, would help.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e) { console.log(e); });
```

Is what I'm using to see the event object at transition time. Its `currentScope` property seems to be the scope of the last item from an `ng-repeat` I have at the bottom of this page. Is this the standard behavior, would you expect the scope to match that of the last "angular" part of the page?

Comment: why you are matching the scope inside event?

Comment: You get the scope of the element that fired the event. Basically somewhere some code did `$scope.$emit('$stateChangeStart', data)` or `$scope.$broadcast('$stateChangeStart', data)`